# Forgot to add primary key column as Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I had created a table like this

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sydShopOrder](
    [rowNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [firstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [employeeNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [productID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [shopID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [department] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [datestamp] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I was intended to make `[rowNumber]` as primary key and make it `identity` column with auto increment. But I forgot to do it. And now the database is up and running in live environment. I had found this bug very late. Is there any way that I can fix this? Make `[rowNumber]` column as identity and auto increment it?

Current screenshot of table looks like this

[image]

Comment: Does rowNumber have data?

Comment: @Karl no its null for now

Comment: You cannot add the `IDENTITY` to an existing column - you'll need to drop that column and re-create it properly, with `IDENTITY` set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop `[rownumber]` and then add with identity

```
Alter Table [dbo].[sydShopOrder] Drop Column rownumber
Go
Alter Table [dbo].[sydShopOrder]
Add rownumber Int Identity(1, 1)
Go
```

If you want to populate the identity field for existing data, better to create another temporary  table, and keep all the records of `[dbo].[sydShopOrder]` in that. After that `truncate` `[dbo].[sydShopOrder]` and then insert the values from that temp table to `[dbo].[sydShopOrder]`

```
CREATE TABLE #temp  ([firstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [employeeNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [productID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [shopID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [department] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [datestamp] [date] NULL)

INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT [firstName],[lastName],[employeeNumber],
       [productID], [shopID],[location],
       [address],[department],[datestamp]
FROM [dbo].[sydShopOrder]

TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[sydShopOrder]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[sydShopOrder]
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Here is a sample [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe850/7)