# writing to a sql column, numbers from 1 to 1000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, field, return-value

i have a table and a field like ID(it has been added later) and i want to write to my table's ID field, numbers from 1 to 1000. for this i wrote a code like this

```
            for (int i = 0; i < 75440; i++)
            {
                baglan.Open();
                SqlCommand kmt = new SqlCommand();
                kmt.Connection = baglan;
                kmt.CommandText = "UPDATE EvrakArsiv SET ID='" + (i + 1) + "' ";
                try
                {
                    kmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                baglan.Close();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 75440; i++)
            {
                baglan.Open();
                SqlCommand kmt = new SqlCommand();
                kmt.Connection = baglan;
                kmt.CommandText = "UPDATE EvrakArsiv SET ID='" + (i + 1) + "' ";
                try
                {
                    kmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                baglan.Close();
            }
```

But it returns a value on the ID Field: all rows value are same. like 9, like 1745, like 3578
whats my wrong?

Comment: Well, you have no `where` clause in your query, so of course it updates the whole table with the same value. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL 2008. how must be "Where Clause" ? can you write for this situation. i want to start from Row1 to last row

Comment: do you want to insert new set of IDs in a blank table?

Comment: no the table is not blan. it have 75440 rows. i have added ID COLUMN after. because of the table has no Primary Key

Comment: then add a new column of type IDENTITY (seed, increment). This will insert values in the column auto incremented by the increment amount specified starting from the seed

Comment: no it wont insert values incremented because the last added field ID is null. so i couldnt be a Primary Key

Comment: if you want to SET Primary Key ID ıt wont let you

Answer (score 0):

WHERE clause is missing in update statements

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Make your `ID` column as `Identity` in your `DBMS`.
Like this [http://stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263019/adding-auto-incrementing-primary-key-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server-2005/19263090#19263090), it will automatically insert values from 1 in table, and then use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command to set `Identity` column for new entry..

Comment: thanks body it gives THE ID field identy but numbers dont increase properly. such as from 1 to 157 is normal but then number gets value 213 then everything goes wrong. whats the reason of this. i have a big database contains 75000 rows. is this the reason of that?

Comment: after i did your said, also must be Primary Key From Design. i did ID Primary key and numbers have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` clause is missing here. What makes your row unique give those conditions in `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to update the column:

```
with cte
As
(
SELECT     <column list separated by comma>, Id, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by <column name>) rno
    FROM EvrakArsiv 
)
Update cte
set Id = rno
```

It will virtually sort the data on the column mentioned in order by clause, and then set the row number to respective Id in table.

Comment: i dont understand,can you explain with an example?

Comment: Suppose I have a table favourite with following columns
Favourites_ID, Game_name, Game_platform, DatePicked. Now I have added one more column New_ID to that. I want to set new_id with the record number in the table.

Then I can use the following query

`with cte
As
(
SELECT     Favourites_ID, Game_name, Game_platform, DatePicked, new_id,
ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Favourites_id) rno
FROM         Favourites
)
Update cte
set new_id = rno`

Comment: It is ok. But setting the column as primary key is not necessary. 
When you do select * from <table name>, by default the result comes sorted on the primary key column.
So if you create the identity column without primary key and then use select * from <table name> order by Id, it will give you correct output.
Primary key is something design decisions, which should be carefully chosen.

Comment: i know, but for me better the numbers seem properly :)